# How to query all employees with 'IT' in titles

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
   select C.CardNumber, C.Name, Text5, Text3 from Access.Credential C
   left join Access.Personnel P
   on C.Name = P.Name
   where C.Active = 1
   and C.Name not like '%Spare%'
   and Text3 like 'IT%'
   or Text5 like '%IT %'
   order by Text5
```

Making a query of all IT personnel including admins and contractors.
Text5 is the employee title and text3 is the IT department. 
I just want titles from either text3 or text5 column with only IT in it. I am almost there but I am getting 'credIT'and other stuff.

Something to keep in mind. IT is not always first in the title ( text 5) , example MGR IT.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think you are looking for this condition:

```
where C.Active = 1 and
      C.Name not like '%Spare%' and
      ' ' + Text3 + ' ' like '% IT %'
```

This adds a space at the beginning and end of the text, and then looks for `IT` surrounded by spaces.

Comment: I think you are missing an `and`, no?

Comment: No worries Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Try by grouping OR condition.

```
Where C.Active = 1 
and C.Name not like '%Spare%' 
and (Text3 like 'IT%' or Text5 like '% IT %')
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for text in the middle of character columns using `LIKE` can't use indexes and is likely to perform pretty badly. If you have governance over the schema (or are good friends with somebody that does), then you might consider using a full text query. This requires adding full text indexes to the searchable tables, but is very well worth the trouble if these kinds of searches are common.

For more information have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Don't be put off by the technical description of filters and such. For "normal" character data...the requisite filters are already present. Just put an index on the table and SQL will "crawl" the text columns and build great indexes from the words in the text.

Then, your query looks something like:

```
select 
  C.CardNumber, C.Name, Text5, Text3 
from 
  Access.Credential C
  left outer join 
  Access.Personnel P
  on 
    C.Name = P.Name
where 
  C.Active = 1 and
  not contains( C.Name'Spare' ) and
  (
    contains( Text3, 'IT' ) or
    contains( Text5, 'IT' )
  )
order by 
  Text5
```

A couple of trivial observations:

It's not at all clear from the query which table contains the Text3 or Text5 columns. You might consider prefixing every referenced column with the alias (C or P)...just to help out the next person that comes along.

Also - avoid subtle logic errors when combining a bunch of conditions with `and` and `or` by using parentheses around the expression. I changed them to what *I think* you meant, but I might have got it wrong ;-)